# TYPO3 v12 Extension Form can't be rendered

Tags: typo3, typo3-12.x

Hello TYPO3 community,

I have an error on a fresh TYPO3(12.3.0) installation via ddev.

I used that commands to create it:

```
  ddev config --php-version 8.1
  ddev config  --project-type=typo3 --docroot=public --create-docroot --php-version 8.1
  ddev start
  ddev composer create "typo3/cms-base-distribution:^12"
  ddev restart
```

When I using a `ContentElement` of type Form, I get the following error:

```
(1/1) #1257246929 TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\View\Exception\InvalidTemplateResourceException

Tried resolving a template file for controller action "FormFrontend->render" in format ".html", but none of the paths contained the expected template file (FormFrontend/Render.html). The following paths were checked: /var/www/html/vendor/typo3/cms-form/Resources/Private/Templates/
```

It seems there is something mixed up with the paths.

When I look into the extension, it is defined as `EXT:form/Resources/Private/Frontend/Templates/`, so the path is set differently than TYPO3 is looking for that.

I try to fix it anyway with a cheap shot:

In the directory `vendor/typo3/cms-form/Resources/Private`
I executed the following two commands

```
mkdir Templates/FormFrontend
cp Frontend/Templates/* Templates/FormFrontend/ -r
```

But as a result, I did get another error.

```
(1/1) #1474905953 TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Exception\TypeDefinitionNotFoundException

Type "Page" not found. Probably some configuration is missing.
```

So I think I have to figure out the real problem.
Can you help me?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you included the TypoScript of EXT:form? 
https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/11.5/en-us/QuickStartForIntegrators/Index.html

Comment: Ok, that worked, but I am curious why that is needed. I think the render part should be included by using the content element.

Comment: Because the plugin configuration is needed (like for other plugins): https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/11.5/typo3/sysext/form/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript